# Is there a possibility to use forest package in context

Tags: context, forest

I'm learning `forest` package and  I was greatly impressed by their potential to build customised trees, I know that there is a possibility to use `tikz` in a `context` document but how about forest.

Comment: Not out of the box. The `forest` package relies on some LaTeX packages and it will require some work to translate it to ConTeXt

Comment: I'm sure this has come up before, but can't recall Sašo's answer.

Comment: Sadly, the answer is still no. I plan to include ConTeXt support in v2.2, but at the moment, I'm having trouble finding even the time to finalize v2.1 ... argh. The (cumbersome) workaround is to generate the trees in LaTeX and include them in a ConTeXt document as images.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović You should make that an answer as it is surely definitive!

Answer (score 3):

<sup>[Sašo's comment as an answer]</sup>

Sadly, the answer is still no. I plan to include ConTeXt support in v2.2, but at the moment, I'm having trouble finding even the time to finalize v2.1 ... argh. The (cumbersome) workaround is to generate the trees in LaTeX and include them in a ConTeXt document as images.